# Trigonometric functions in constant array initializers in OpenCL

Tags: constants, opencl

I have a number of vectors I would like to use in my application. In a square grid, these are the vectors of the cardinal and diagonal directions in which I can go from the center of a cell. My OpenCL kernels will use them often so I would like to define them in constant memory. I have written the following piece of code in my kernel file:

```
#define N_RADIAN  2 * M_PI_4_F
#define NE_RADIAN 1 * M_PI_4_F
#define E_RADIAN  0 * M_PI_4_F
#define SE_RADIAN 7 * M_PI_4_F
#define S_RADIAN  6 * M_PI_4_F
#define SW_RADIAN 5 * M_PI_4_F
#define W_RADIAN  4 * M_PI_4_F
#define NW_RADIAN 3 * M_PI_4_F

constant float2 E[8] = {
(float2)(cos( N_RADIAN), sin( N_RADIAN)),   // N
(float2)(cos(NE_RADIAN), sin(NE_RADIAN)),   // NE
(float2)(cos( E_RADIAN), sin( E_RADIAN)),   // E
(float2)(cos(SE_RADIAN), sin(SE_RADIAN)),   // SE
(float2)(cos( S_RADIAN), sin( S_RADIAN)),   // S
(float2)(cos(SW_RADIAN), sin(SW_RADIAN)),   // SW
(float2)(cos( W_RADIAN), sin( W_RADIAN)),   // W
(float2)(cos(NW_RADIAN), sin(NW_RADIAN))    // NW
};
```

This code refuses to compile for me. The error message I get is 
**error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant**. I can understand it if the mathematical functions has to be called on the device for the array to get its values. If that is the case I can make a kernel which computes these values without much fuss. However, this method would be more convenient for me. Is there any way in which I can get these values declared in constant memory? Do you see any other problems with this approach or the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way to do it with constants is to go with something like this:

```
  constant float2 E[8] = {
  (0.0           , 1.0          ) ,   // N
  (CL_M_SQRT1_2  , CL_M_SQRT1_2 ) ,   // NE
  (1.0           , 0.0          ) ,   // E
  (CL_M_SQRT1_2  , -CL_M_SQRT1_2) ,   // SE
  (0.0           , -1.0         ) ,   // S
  (-CL_M_SQRT1_2 , -CL_M_SQRT1_2) ,   // SW
  (-1.0          , 0.0          ) ,   // W
  (-CL_M_SQRT1_2 , CL_M_SQRT1_2 )     // NW
  };
```

The problem may actually be a blessing in disguise. This alternative code generates values accurate to the limitation of 32-bit IEEE float. The original code is a little off due to the difference between pi/4 and M_PI_4_F. For example, the original code generates cosine (north) = -4.37114e-008 instead of the presumably intended value of zero.

Comment: Simple and accurate. Maybe I overthought my original plan.